# How to solve `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency` of `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, warnings, react-hooks, eslint

I am here to ask something about **react hooks** and **missing dependencies**.

I try to be concise, this is warning message I have in my console

```
Compiled with warnings.

./src/views/categories/Categories.tsx
  Line 14:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatcher'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

the code of the hook *useEffect*

```
const [categoriesList, dispatcher] = useCategoryList({})

useEffect(() => {
  !isOpenConfirmAddModal && dispatcher.fetchCategories()
}, [isOpenConfirmAddModal])
```

and this is the code of the custom hook *useCategoryList*

```
export const useCategoryList = (
  initialState: CategoriesData
): CategoriesListHook => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(categoryReducer, initialState)

  const fetchCategories = async () => {
    const categories = await getCategories()
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_CATEGORIES, data: categories })
  }

  // ....

  return [
    state,
    {
      fetchCategories
      // ...
    }
  ]
}
```

if I set the dispatcher as dependency

```
useEffect(() => {
  !isOpenConfirmAddModal && dispatcher.fetchCategories()
}, [isOpenConfirmAddModal, dispatcher])
```

and the effect in the application is an eternal loop of call to `dispatcher.fetchCategories()`,  it seems that `dispatch` is constantly updating itself and the loop is never ending.

I tried some other coouple of attempts suggested in SO, but I never saw a *dispatcher* from a *useReducer* within a *useEffect*.

Ideas, thanks!

Comment: did you try `usecallback` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom hook you can not re create fetchCategories and possibly other methods using useMemo:

```
export const useCategoryList = initialState => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
    categoryReducer,
    initialState
  );

  const methods = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      fetchCategories: async () => {
        const categories = await getCategories();
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_CATEGORIES,
          data: categories,
        });
      },
      //other methods
    }),
    []//no dependencies
  );

  return [state, methods];
};
```

Now fetchCategies should not change during component life cycle so you can do:

```
const [categoriesList, {fetchCategories}] = useCategoryList({});
useEffect(() => {
  !isOpenConfirmAddModal && fetchCategories();
}, [fetchCategories]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of  `useCallback` inside the custom hook itself to wrap the `fetchCategories` method giving its own dependency array.

```
const fetchCategories = useCallback(async () => {
  const categories = await getCategories()
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_CATEGORIES, data: categories })
},[<your dependencies>])
// check and update this dependency array
```

I think it is more abstract way to do this.

Comment: Why is initalState a dependency?

Comment: @HMR i was trying to give an idea about to its own dependencies.

Comment: issue keeps staying with this approach

Comment: what are dependeny you are using in this callback?